# Expo Deep link on Android with subdomain not opening the app

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I want to open my app when a user enters a domain like `https://subdomain.myapp.com/post`, where `subdomain` is dynamic and can be anything. My Expo (SDK 46) configuration is the following:

```
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "autoVerify": true,
          "data": [
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.myapp.com",
              "pathPattern": "/post"
            }
          ],
          "category": ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"]
        }
      ]
```

I also have added this file to all possible subdomains `/.well-known/assetlinks.json` as the following:

```
[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.app.app",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["XX:38:A6:XX:28:XX:72:BB:29:CF:C7:25:3E:05:85:A4:D0:00:98:83:11:64:12:C8:06:32:A5:70:7B:BC:71:XX"]
    }
  }
]
```

I generated a new build and tried testing links coming from Slack and Gmail and it always open on the browser, same for the following command:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://subdomain.myapp.com/post/my-post-id"
```

but I never get the option to open it in my app. Any ideas of what I'm missing?